# JHipster and SAML Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, saml, jhipster

Just wondering if anyone has successfully implemented `SAML` integration in a `JHipster` application?
If so are there any samples or good tutorials I could follow?

Comment: I integrated Spring Boot with Okta's SAML last year. Maybe this will help: https://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/integrating_node_js_ruby_and